# I want to insert nums of visiters into mysql DB on 23:59:59, but my DB haves unexpected datas

Tags: mysql, node.js

Currently, I started web develop. But, there are some problems.
I want to insert total nums of visiters that visit my site between 0:0:0 to 23:59:59.
But, in my mysql DB table, already inserted unexpected datas.
For example, data should be inserted into the DB after 23:59:59 on June 20, but for some reason, unwanted data continues to be inserted into the data, as if for July 3rd.
Did I make an error in the code?

Here's my node.js code.
I installed all the necessary modules.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var date = new Date();
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = date.getMonth();
    let day = date.getDate();
    var today = year + " " + month + " " + day;

    var j = schedule.scheduleJob({ hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 1 }, function () {
            console.log(year + " " + month + " " + day);
            connection.query(
                `INSERT INTO visiter VALUES (${year}, ${month + 1},${day}, ${count});`
            );
            count = 0;
    });

    console.log(req.session.lastVisit);
    if (req.session.lastVisit != today) {
        req.session.lastVisit = today;
        count++;
    }

    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'html', 'index.html'), (err, data) => {
        try {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            console.log(count);
            res.end(data);
        } catch (err) {
            res.writeHead(404, () => {
                console.log("Page Not Found!")
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Your question has the assumption that something is wrong in your database, but no info is in the question about ho this database (table `visiter`) was defined. The `INSERT` statement in your code gives the impression that is could be done smarter....

Comment: May I show you my database information? Or what do you mean by the fact that there is no info defined about the data base?

Comment: I do mean the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE visiter\G`  (unless it has info that you do not want to share...)

Comment: Your insert query assumes that the table has a fixed number of columns in a fixed order. That not only makes it harder to debug but will also make it fail if you ever need to modify the table.

Comment: to Luuk;
I have this error "sudo: mysql: command not found" but I already installed mysql module...

Comment: Try making your scheduler outside the route, and call when the file is required, like define a function in the global and a global variable count, Ill post an Answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

Try making your scheduler outside the route, in your example, your scheduler will init each time there is a route hit, which is not required,

> For Example

```
_count = 0;
function scheduleDatabaseWrite() {
    const { year, month, day, today } = GetCurrentDateMonthYear();
    schedule.scheduleJob({ hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 1 }, () => {
        connection.query(
            `INSERT INTO visiter VALUES (${year}, ${month + 1},${day}, ${count});`
        );
        _count = 0; //And do this re-initialization only if the database write is success 
    });
}

function GetCurrentDateMonthYear() {
    var date = new Date();
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = date.getMonth(); // also you might need to check this logic as well, you want js month index or real world number, date.getMonth() - will return value starting from 0 and end's at 11, if you want 1 - 12 then add 1 to it, like date.getMonth()+1
    let day = date.getDate(); 
    var today = year + " " + month + " " + day;
    return { year, month, day, today };
}

scheduleDatabaseWrite();

p.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const { year, month, day, today } = GetCurrentDateMonthYear();
    console.log(req.session.lastVisit);
    if (req.session.lastVisit != today) {
        req.session.lastVisit = today;
        _count++;
    }

    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'html', 'index.html'), (err, data) => {
        try {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            console.log(count);
            res.end(data);
        } catch (err) {
            res.writeHead(404, () => {
                console.log("Page Not Found!")
            });
        }
    })
});
```